# How can we hide include layout programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to include one layout in my application. So that I have used

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/support_layout"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/support"/>
```

I have referenced this include tag in my java file using View.

```
View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.support_layout);
```

But at some point of my code I have to Hide this layout.
so that I used **v.GONE**

But it's not Hiding.
I want to reference those text and button attributes located in XML programatically.
How can I do that?

There is my support.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/support_layout"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn" 
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to hide that `View`?

Comment: try to use v.setVisibility(View.GONE); instead only v.GONE.

Answer (score 62):

Since `<include/>` is not a View type in android and `visibility` is the property of `View`, we can not access the visibility from included layout's reference.

However if you are using kotlin with view binding, we can get the reference of root of the included layout like `binding.supportLayout.root` which probably will be one of the `View (ConstraintLayout, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.)`

Now we have reference of view means we can play with their visibility like below code.

```
binding.supportLayout.root.visibility = View.GONE
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Working, Thank you for the good explanation, other answers are not working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with view binding and can be achieved by just `findViewById()`, don't know you even included it

Comment: @Farid Who uses findViewById() now a days, Its quite inefficient. Also I haven't said that this is the only way. This is one of the possible answer.

Answer (score 19):

Put that view into a linearlayout and hide the linearlayout. It will work.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/support_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    layout="@layout/support"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:width="match_parent" /> </LinearLayout>
```

And don't forget writing Linearlayout instead of View.

Briefly, instead of

```
View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.support_layout);
```

Do this

```
LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.support_layout);
```

Comment: Negates the use of using include tags.The idea is to make hierarchy flat.

Comment: same for using include with merge tags

Answer (score 18):

We need to see your actual implementation of hiding that `View` you mentioned.

But, straight from reading of your question, I presume that you've might do it the wrong way.

To hide or make a view invisible, use this:

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Bear in mind that this does not remove the view compeletly; it would still remain in your layout and you could get a reference to it or even try to manipulate it.

To remove it compeletly, use this instead:

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Now if you call this, yourView would be compeletly removed from the layout. You will no longer able to get a reference to it.

Comment: if i will user View.Visible again then this layout will be visible or not??

Comment: @DharmasaiSeerapu, of course. If you call `yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` the said 'View' will be visible again.

Comment: But in my case It is showing error when accessing elements in the layout

Comment: @Dharmasai Seerapu, it would be hard to solve without knowing what you do in tour code. Please update your question alongside with that portion of code.

Comment: I will lost my reference to it when I set the visibility to View.GONE? I've been trying this for ages and I can toggle between View.GONE and View.VISIBLE. I can make it View.VISIBLE from being View.GONE.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide this "included" layout with calling [setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) :

```
v.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

and show it later with calling :

```
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

To reference button and textview from support layout you can use findViewById method on your included View (I'm not sure but I think it's even not mandatory, you can call it directly on your activity's view) :

```
View supportLayout = (View) findViewById(R.id.support_layout);
Textview txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

(if it's not working try with : Button btn = (Button) supportLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn);)

-- FYI --

When you give attributs to include tags it [override ones of the included layout](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include) (there support_layout LinearLayout) so you don't need to do that

Answer (score 3):

you must use like this `includedLayoutId.viewId.visibility = View.GONE` in this case you can access to included view, now for example:

loading.xml

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_fileName="loading.json"
    app:lottie_loop="true" />
```

in fragment_a.xml :

```
 <include layout="@layout/loading"
            android:id="@+id/anim_loading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"/>
```

and finally use it `animLoading.loading.visibility = View.GONE`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the new `ConstraintLayout`.
This is how I do it with `widget.Group`

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_action"
        layout="@layout/bottom_bar_back_action"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_group"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="bottom_bar_action" />
```

Then you can hide the include layout by doing `binding.bottomBarGroup.visibility = View.GONE`. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
     // 1 - copy this 
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           tools:context=".Add">
       <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="gone"
          android:onClick="onclick_gone_include"/>

       <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="visible"
          android:onClick="onclick_visible_include"/>
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/support_layout"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
          >

          <include
              layout="@layout/support"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

       //code
          //2 copy this to Add cliass
        //this methods on click in Add class
         public void onclick_gone_include(View view) {
             View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.support_layout);//view is the v
             v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         }
              
          public void onclick_visible_include(View view) {
             View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.support_layout);        
             v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

         //3 activity that included 'support activity'
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:context=".Add"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="textview1"
                />
        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview2"
         />
     </LinearLayout>
```